# SQL server Pivot on Multiple Columns- Another dimension

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use a pivot on multiple columns. Currently, I am able to achieve this with just one column. My current method returns:

```
Membership  Item1
DO1          400
Neither       21
Plan A        69
Plan B        53
```

But here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Membership  Item1   Item2   Item3   Item3    Item4    Item5
DO1          30     300      25        14       10      144
Neither      35     250      30        30       5       125
Plan A       50     100      25        25       5       254
Plan B       100     25      15        25       4       123
```

Here is my code

```
WITH CTE_SQL
AS 
(
    SELECT CaseId
          ,Item1 AS Number1
          ,[Membership] -- ,Item2 AS Number2,Item3 AS Number3,Item4 AS Number4,Item5 AS Number5
          FROM TABLE1
          WHERE [Membership] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT [Membership]
       ,Item1 --,Item2--,Item3 AS 'Item3',Item4 AS 'Item4',Item5 AS 'Item5'
FROM 
(
    SELECT CaseId
          ,Number1
          ,[Membership] --,[Item2],[Item3],[Item4],[Item5]
          FROM CTE_SQL
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(CaseId) 
    FOR Number1 IN (Item1)
) AS pvt
ORDER BY [Membership]
```

Any insight?
Update Here is the table schema

```
ColumnName  DataType    Allow Nulls
..........  ........    ...........
CaseId    nvarchar(50)      No
Membership  nvarchar(50)    Yes
Item1      nvarchar(50)     Yes
Item2      nvarchar(50)     Yes
Item3      nvarchar(50)     Yes
Item4     nvarchar(50)      Yes
Item5     nvarchar(50)      Yes
```

---

So here is an update to my last. This is my source data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(CASENumber NVARCHAR(50),Membership NVARCHAR(50),Item1 NVARCHAR(50),Item2 NVARCHAR(50),Item3 NVARCHAR(50),Item4 NVARCHAR(50),Item5 NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT 'Case001', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case001', 'PlanA','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'PlanA','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case001', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case001', 'PlanA','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'PlanA','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case001', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case004', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case005', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case001', 'PlanB','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case002', 'D01','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Case003', 'Neither','Gold','Silver','Diamond','Steel','Wood'
```

And here I was stuck with my code and the output I have so far:

```
WITH CTE_SQL
  AS
  (
      SELECT CASENumber,Item1 AS Number1,[Membership]--,Item2 AS Number2,
      Item3 AS  Number3,Item4 Number4,Item5 AS Number5
      FROM  dbo.TABLE1
      WHERE [Membership] IS NOT NULL 

  )
  SELECT Membership,Gold as 'Item1' --,Item2--,Item3 AS 'Item3',
  Item4 AS 'Item4',Item5 AS 'Item5' 
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT CaseNumber,Number1,Membership--,[Item2],[Item3],[Item4],[Item5]
      FROM  CTE_SQL 
   ) AS p 
   PIVOT 
   (
      COUNT(CASENumber)
      FOR Number1 in(Gold)  
   ) as pvt
```

**Current Output**

```
Membership  Item1
.........   .....
D01           7
Neither       9
PlanA         4
PlanB        13
```

**Intended Output**

```
Membership  Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5
..........  .....   .....   .....   .....   .....
D01         7        7        7       7       7
Neither     9        9       9        9       9
PlanA       4        4        4       4       4
PlanB       13      13        13      13      13
```

Please note that all the elements under items1 columns are gold. The same applies to items 2-5 with `Silver`, `Diamond`, `Steel` and `Wood` respectively.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: The sample data is provided above before the code

Comment: I thought that was the expected result?

Comment: The first table is what I am currently getting. The second table is my expected.

Comment: Yeah, from where did you get that?

Comment: This example is more of made up.

Comment: Any insight will be appreciated

Comment: The main idea I am looking for here is how to incorporate item2,item3,item4 and item5. I got the the first part working well.

Comment: Can you post the schema for `TABLE1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic pivot to get the result.

Declare variable to get the columns for pivot

```
 DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

 SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Number1 + ']', '[' + Number1 + ']')
                   FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Number1 FROM #TEMP) PV 
                   ORDER BY Number1
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT Membership, Number1, 
                 -- Get the count here
                 COUNT(CASEID) OVER(PARTITION BY Membership,Number1) CNT 
                 FROM #TEMP
                 WHERE Membership IS NOT NULL
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR Number1 IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY Membership;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd06e/2) to view result

**EDIT :**

As per your update, if you need the count of CaseId for each member, you could use the below query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Membership, 
    COUNT(CASEID) OVER(PARTITION BY Membership) CNT 
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE Membership IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Membership,CNT AS Item1,CNT AS Item2,CNT AS Item3,CNT AS Item3,CNT AS  Item4,CNT AS Item5
FROM CTE
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38e7f/1) to view result

**EDIT 2 :**

Dear friend. This one is an easy process. We can do it without pivoting. We can use `PARTITION BY()` method in `Sql Server`, which get the total count of `CASENUMBER` for each `Membership`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Membership],
COUNT(Item1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Membership]) AS Item1,
COUNT(Item2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Membership]) AS Item2,
COUNT(Item3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Membership]) AS Item3,
COUNT(Item4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Membership]) AS Item4,
COUNT(Item5) OVER(PARTITION BY [Membership]) AS Item5
FROM  TABLE1
WHERE [Membership] IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY MEMBERSHIP
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf78f/1) to view result

**RESULT**

```
x-------------x-----------x----------x----------x---------x---------x
|  Membership |   Item1   |   Item2  |   Item3  |  Item4  |  Item5  |
x-------------x-----------x----------x----------x---------x---------x           
|    D01      |      7    |    7     |     7    |    7    |     7   |
|    Neither  |      9    |    9     |     9    |    9    |     9   |
|    Plan A   |      4    |    4     |     4    |    4    |     4   |
|    Plan B   |     13    |    13    |    13    |   13    |    13   |
x-------------x-----------x----------x----------x---------x---------x
```

Comment: Thanks but if you look at my query original query, item1 ( and the commented item2 -item5) are real columns. Your solution only has Number1. 
I am looking for a situation when CREATE TABLE TEMP(CASEID INT,Membership VARCHAR(30),NUMBER1 VARCHAR(30),NUMBER2 VARCHAR(30),NUMBER3 VARCHAR(30),NUMBER4 VARCHAR(30),NUMBER5 VARCHAR(30))

Comment: Do you want to take the count of Case_id in each Membership from your source table(Table1) ? @user3424320

Comment: Yes that is my intention.

Comment: So don't need pivot right? You just need the count of Case_id in each type of membership and show the table like source table. Right? @user3424320

Comment: I do need a Pivot. Keep in mind that I am counting the Caseids based on membership and item1 to item5

Comment: Ohk. So if the count of Caseids for **DO1** is two, for Item1 to Item5, u need to update values with two? @user3424320

Comment: I have updated. Please check and feel free to ask for any changes. @user3424320

Comment: Not quite. What I am trying to achieve the count of Caseids for Number 1-5 based on the membership. So instead of using NULLS for Number 1-5 columns. Make them values (characters is fine). So lets say I have 12418 cases. I want the count of Numer1 - 5 columns based on the membership. Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I am not clear fully. Can u edit the question, add the souce table with data and a table for expected output? @user3424320

Comment: The source data is not something I can provide right here. That is why I provided the initial example with my code. If you create a table with the schema I provided and run the my code, you should be able to see what I am currently getting and that could give a clue to what I am trying to do.

Comment: See my friend. Its not a competetion to find solution here. The question and desired must be clear inorder to solve the issue. You know what you are expecting, but you should present question in a way that any one should understand from ur question. Please edit and update in question, else no one can answer. @user3424320

Comment: Don't give **CLUE**s and all. Please specify the exact requirement in the question. @user3424320

Comment: I apologize for my earlier comment. My English is not too good. I will update

Comment: No problem. I didn't blame u my friend. I just suggested to do so else no one can understand.  :) @user3424320

Comment: Yes. Now its clear from your question. This is the perfect way of asking question :) @user3424320

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. I guess I over analyzed the issue.